# using console escape color codes in sed

Tags: perl, sed, colors, console

I need to color lines that start with `#`.

I have following code in perl, which works fine:

```
echo 'aaa\n#bbb\nccc' | perl -pe "s/(#.*)$/\e[0;32m\1\e[0m/"
```

I am trying to do the same in sed, but it just prints the color codes, instead of the color:

```
echo 'aaa\n#bbb\nccc' | sed -r "s/(#.*)$/\e[0;32m\1\e[0m/"
aaa
e[0;32m#bbbe[0m
ccc
```

Why are the color codes not working in sed, and what do I have to do differently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use '\o033' instead of '\e':

```
$ echo -e 'aaa\n#bbb\nccc' | sed -r "s/(#.*)$/\o033[0;32m\1\o033[0m/"
```